# Dell keyboard backlight is not working

Tags: 16.04, dell, keyboard-backlight

I saw that the keyboard backlight was not working. How can that be fixed?

**Hardware/OS**

- Dell Latitude E6540
- Kubuntu 16.04 (`xenial`)

Answer (score 19):

You may want to check the brightness settings for the Dell keyboard. The following procedure worked for me:

1. Show the configured brightness:

   ```
   $ cat /sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
   0
   ```
2. See the maximum brightness:

   ```
   $ cat /sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell\:\:kbd_backlight/max_brightness
   4
   ```
3. Set the desired level of brightness (here: 4):

   ```
   $ echo 4 | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
   ```

Slightly related: You might also want to configure the time-out interval for the backlight, using the `stop_timeout` setting.
See also the article [How to Configure the Keyboard Backlight Time-Out Interval in Ubuntu Linux](https://www.dell.com/support/article/de/de/debsdt1/sln308123/how-to-configure-the-keyboard-backlight-time-out-interval-in-ubuntu-linux?lang=en) in the Dell knowledge base.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help on this, I would have never figured this out on my own.

Comment: This works, but how can I make it persist after a reboot / sleep cycle?  The brightness always resets to 0, and the keyboard buttons don't work to trigger the keys to light up.  Every time I open up the laptop I have to set the desired brightness manually. I was hoping the latest kernel would fix it, but didn't help.  I've installed every update possible.  - DELL E6510

Comment: I wonder what is the catch for this not being in the GUI.. seems straightforward

Comment: it´s working, thank you...