# Keyboard backlight not working after fresh install of Ubuntu bionic

Tags: 18.04, gnome, ubuntu-gnome, dual-graphics

I have a Samsung Odyssey laptop which has both Nvidia and intel graphics. I am dual booting windows10 and Ubuntu18.04 but the keyboard backlight doesn’t work after pressing the hot keys (Fn + F9) when in Ubuntu environment. I read that the intel graphics is what controls the backlight so I switched to using the intel graphics but it still doesn’t work. Is there a work around for it.

Comment: the phrasing of the title leads us to believe it worked with another version of ubuntu; is that the case? if not this is a driver/kernel issue. you'll have to find the exact part number identifier for that keyboard and see if any attempts have been made to add this keyboard (or similar) to the Linux Kernel if not will not have the pretty lights under anything other than windows. On an off-chance : does this solution work for you : https://askubuntu.com/a/644420/307184 ? this :https://askubuntu.com/a/1076394/307184?

Comment: apparently Kernel updates can sometimes fix it : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086070/keyboard-backlight-ubuntu-18-10-not-working given with ubuntu 18.04 you're on kernel 4, you wouldn't have this issue with ubuntu 19.04 which is on kernel 5.

Comment: @tatsu no I have not tried on other ubuntu versions and none of the solutions you pointed out worked for me. I am starting to think that it actually is a kernel issue. I will try to upgrade my kernel and see if that fixes it.

Comment: So I installed kernel 5.1 but anytime I try to load it at boot it gives the error ‘error: you need to load the kernel first.’

Comment: I’ve been able to fix the issue with the kernel. I am now running on kernel 5.1.2 but the backlight still doesn’t work.

Comment: you'll have to motivate some devs to add it to the kernel or add it yourself.